# JetBrains add language scope to multiple abbreviations?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rider, live-templates

How do you add additional language scopes to multiple live templates in JetBrains IDEs?

I know you can select each live template individually and click the change 'Change' link next to 'Applicable in ...' to update the language scope it applies to, but how do you update the scope on an entire list of templates at one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the first live template in the list and `SHIFT+CLICK` the last template in the list to select those templates and all those in-between. (Alternatively, you can cherry-pick/select templates with `CTRL+CLICK`)

Once selected, `RIGHT-CLICK` (mac: `OPTION+CLICK`) the selection and choose `Change context`. Select the languages you would like to scope the live templates to as normal.